# Paraview Color maps

Tags: visualization, raycasting, paraview

I have an MRI volumetric array and a probability map on top of it which maps from 0 to 1.

I'd like to have the MRI shown as slices (one for each plane) in black and white, and the probability map as a volume over it (ray cast) on a scale from blue, 0 opacity to red full opacity.

For now I can't even overlay the two volumes using different colormaps. How do I do it?

[image: Here is the pipeline as shown on Paraview]

Answer (score 2):

I would comment because I don't believe this is an answer but I don't have the reputation to comment.

For different colormaps you need different scalar attributes names.

If they have the same name they will be colored by the same colormap.

If this is not helpfull, let us know more details of your datasets so we can help you better!

Comment: you can use the **Calculator** or **Python Calculator** to change the name of the scalar array.